# Add Data attribute to element and dynamically add value from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible to assign a data value to the element below - and use the numbers in the string as the value with jQuery/Vanilla JS?

I want this:

```
<div class="priceinfo col5">2560kr</div>
```

To look like this:

```
<div class="priceinfo col5" data-price="2560">2560kr</div>
```

The value is dynamic - the class of the element is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with the jQuery [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) method:

```
var someValue = 2560;
$('.priceinfo.col5').attr('data-price', someValue);
```

You can set any attribute, including custom attributes such as HTML5 `data-` attributes, using `attr()`.

---

You can also [pass a function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) instead of a fixed value to `.attr()`:

```
$('.priceinfo.col5').attr('data-price', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    return parseInt(text, 10); //drops the non-numeric characters at the end of the text
});
```

This is extremely useful when there are multiple elements in the jQuery set -- multiple elements with the classes `priceinfo` and `col5`.

---

If the value might sometimes have initial non-numeric characters, then you could use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to parse the text:

```
$('.priceinfo.col5').attr('data-price', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var matches = /\d+/.exec(text);
    if (!matches) {return '';}
    return parseInt(matches[0], 10);
});
```

Comment: Hi! I would like to create the data value from the string in the element. Since this is a dynamic number i cant set a value myself with the script.

Comment: @Zev Spitz I just realized a situation where I will have a non-numeric character before the numbers in the string- is it possible to account for that as well?

Comment: @Zev Spitz thanks - that worked great. I noticed two other situations that made the script not working - in one instance I had a comma in the middle. this made the data price only to be the number before the comma.  the second instance there where one of these repeating elements that only had text - no numbers. the element that only had text made the script not work on the elements with numbers inside it. the first one I can avoid, no commas. but the second I cant. Is it any way to account for that?

Comment: @JerrySvensson RE commas, you can make the regular expression more complex, to account for commas and decimal separators, or you can find a [Javascript library that parses text into numbers while taking into account number formats](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). RE empty text -- Can empty values be treated as 0?

Comment: @Zev Spitz Seems like it cant be treated as 0 - you last snippet gave me this:  
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: I have to say, this answer has changed dramatically from my original answer. Next time, @ZevSpitz, consider writing your own answer instead of changing mine so extensively.

Comment: @ZevSpitz in the first edit you say "`data` can no longer be used to set HTML5 data- attributes". This was mostly the key part of my answer that changed. Is that true? It works for me, and it seems to be valid based on https://api.jquery.com/data/, I can't see anything on there that says you can't set it this way.

Comment: From that [link](https://api.jquery.com/data/) -- _The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)._ It is certainly possible to set/get element-associated data using `.data`, but this won't be stored in the HTML `data-*` attribute, but in an internal Javascript object.

Comment: ah, I see. i didn't realize that it doesn't store the resulting data in the html. In that case, I would view my original answer as being completely wrong. I'll leave it up to you whether you want to submit an answer or just keep this one.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with plain javascript as well:

```
function setAttribute(selector, attribute, value) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
        elements[index].setAttribute(attribute, (typeof value === "function" ? value(elements[index]) : value));
    }
}
```